# Custom Shortcut Not Working Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: shortcuts

I wanted to make a custom shortcut to type the "€" symbol since I couldn't figure out how to type it natively with my keyboard. I tried multiple times to type the key, but it never worked no matter which shortcut I tried that wasn't already taken up by another shortcut.

Is there a fix for this?

Edit: I am using the English (US) format, but my keyboard also has support for AltGr and has the Euro symbol on the 5, but I never figured out how to do it. I have the Language set to English (United States) and Formats set to Ireland.

Comment: Have you tried the 'right alt'+e? It works for me ( Kubuntu 20.04.3 + spanish keyboard, HP Envy ).

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the keyboard in use (English US/UK) and what you have set in `Settings -> Language and Region`

Comment: @24601 I have added the requested edits, hope it helps!

Comment: @JoepieEs For me, it does nothing, it is 'right alt' + e + = to get it, but I wanted an easier way to get it, sort of like 'shift' + 4 for example.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>20AC</kbd> will print a `€` symbol.  It works for any unicode symbol, actually.  After you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>, an underlined `U` will appear, type the <kbd>20AC</kbd> Unicode and then hit the space bar. Voila, a `€` symbol will appear.

Comment: It works, but I was more looking for either to replace the 'shift' + 4 input (that being "4") and make that switch to "€" or find another easier to do shortcut, which making my own shortcut unfortunately hasn't worked. Turning on the "Compose Key" and making it "Right Alt" works, but it still isn't quite the solution I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I added the English (US, euro on 5) input source to put the Euro sign over the 5 key.

**Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources**

[image]

After selecting `English(US)`, choose the layout, in this case `English (US, euro on 5)`.

[image]